# Web Development: Complex processes: Are state machines the (only?) way to go?

Tags: rest, language-agnostic, web, state-machine

In web development there is a lot of focus on REST-style architectures, with the objectives of minimizing (or eliminating) state. The web frameworks that I have seen all emphasize this style (Django, Rails, flask, etc.).

While I agree that this is a good fit for the web in general, there are also many cases where this is inadequate. In particular I am thinking of the case where you want the user to follow a process, i.e. you want to offer a number of steps and these steps should be completed in a certain order (possibly with optional steps, deviating paths, etc.)

A good example of this might be a shopping cart: First you have to make your selection, then enter your address, choose shipment type, enter your payment details, finish. You don't want the user to skip any of these steps and the process can become a lot more complex. Ideally I would want this process to be defined in a separate place to separate this logic from the rest of the implementation.

Now my questions:

1. Are finite state machines the way to go here? Do they still work well if these processes become complex and need to change a lot (e.g. this step should go here, this step should go into this process instead, etc)?
2. What options are offered by/for web frameworks (not any in particular I am interested in the best solutions)?
3. What are interesting / good examples of where such processes occur? Shopping carts are an obvious example but I am sure there are lots more.

Comment: An interesting example of state machines would be a set top box for a cable company such as Virgin, etc. These can get quite complex, and a huge pain in the arse to code as the boxes are often very limited in power and the majority of bandwidth is reserved for audio/video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they are. Using state machines (workflows) is an appropriate solution for the problem you described. If designed well it can make your code more cleaner, remove mess from the code. Logic of each state and transition logic are incapsulated within a State class object so the code looks cleaner and more maintainable . Implementations may vary (say, the place you keep your transition logic - within state or create a separate transition manager) and don't match canonical description of state machine in discrete math so you'd better try what works for you better.
2. For Ruby you can check workflow: https://github.com/geekq/workflow or stonepath: https://github.com/bokmann/stonepath. State machine pattern is also can be found in javascript frameworks (SpoutCore). It's not difficult to implement your own small state machine engine.
3. Interesting examples? Lots of them. Processing orders, banking operations, games.  I used state machine when created behaviour correction module which includes phychological tests, games, video. The transitions from state to state depended there on if tests are answered correctly, if game played successfully etc.

PS. I used the terms of state machine and workflow as synonyms but they are not the same; it was discussed here: http://jmettraux.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/state-machine-workflow-engine/ . You can also find some Ruby code and links there.